# windows WDK routines naming rule

Tags: wdk

Does anyone knows about the windows WDK routines naming rule? for example,ExAllocatePoolWithTag() ,the prefix Ex- mean what? I can not find document about the naming rule, thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok，I find it， here is a link to microsoft docs, enjoy~
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/what-does-the-zw-prefix-mean-

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/windows-kernel-mode-run-time-library

Comment: add one more manual to explain "Rtl" in windows driver routine name